# phpunit is not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, pear

I am trying to get phpunit to work on my ubuntu 11.10 installation.
I have installed PHPUnit using PEAR, as suggested [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) and then I prepared a very small testing class:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
set_include_path(get_include_path().':/usr/share/php');
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/OutputTestCase.php';

class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(FALSE);
    }
}
// $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('ExampleTest');
// PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run($suite);
```

When I run this via the command line executable phpunit, I get nothing.
When I uncomment the last two lines and run the file with the php executable, I get proper output (Failed asserting that  is true. etc..)

Further more, when I try **phpunit --version**, I still get nothing!

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out...I forgot to add /usr/share/php in the include_path in php.ini. grrrrrr...